# if/else statement confusion

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm thinking about making a small semi-game where you respond to a mysterious void about things. The user sees a question on-screen, types a response in the textbox and clicks the reply button, and the script replies.

My main problem is to understand the logic behind all this.

For example:

Do you like apples?
 A1:Yes
 A2:No

```
if(yes){
say this
} else if(no){
say that
}
```

What would be the appropriate syntax in this case? Because i'm really really confused right now, it may seem like a very noob-question, but jQuery is getting on my nerves.

Comment: Well you wouldn't be using jQuery for a start. You would be using Javascript.  jQuery is a javascript library.  It has no if statement. Javascript does. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: see example of prompt https://jsfiddle.net/2uobbz9u/

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with JQuery

Comment: Checkbox will be better than textbox, JQuery is option, you can using JavaScript to working on it.

Comment: I removed the `JQuery` tag, and replaced it with `Javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input'),
  output = document.getElementById('output');

input.onkeyup = function(event) {
  switch (this.value.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'chicken':
      output.innerText = "I like chicken too";
      break;
    case 'meat':
      output.innerText = "mmmmm, meat!!";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="output">Huh?</div>
</form>
```

You could also just do this

```js
var isYes = true;
(isYes) ? /* Do this */ : /* Do this */ ;
```

Saves you lines of code

Edit: As you had requested I have created a snippet. Try it out, type in chicken/meat

Comment: See my earlier comment

Comment: @AlexanderElsano try the snippet, type in chicken or meat and it changes the output div's text to some pre-defined sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Boolean (true,false) type of scenario you can can just use an if/else type of statement:

```
var is_yes = true;
if(is_yes){
    // Do this
} else {
    // Do that
}
```

Comment: Yeah i understand that far, but what should i type if actually want to process the data coming from the textbox itself?